# How to add a new network card to the MAAS web interface

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

I am working on setting up a test openstack implementation on Ubuntu. When I installed the machine which will be my region controller I didn't notice that only one of the network cards was enabled. I set up MAAS and then enabled the second card by editing /etc/network/interfaces and running ifup eth1. Now I can see that the interface for the card is up in ifconfig, but I don't see the card when I go to the Add Network page in the MAAS management web app.